# Only bind user can connect to Postfix server using LDAP

Tags: postfix, authentication, ldap, active-directory

I have a functioning Active Directory server, but whenever I try to authenticate against the Postfix server that uses it (with `saslauthd`) I notice that only the bind user can connect. Whenever I try to connect to the server with valid credentials, it does not work.

Any idea as to where I can debug why only the bind user can log in?
I know it's possible, because I have another setup with Postfix authenticating against LDAP with all users, but I cannot seem to figure out what the difference is between those.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly after posting this question, I found the answer myself.

The problem was that my `ldap_search_base` had the bind user `cn=postfix` in `/etc/saslauthd.conf`. After changing the search base to the Users OU, it started to work :)